# Find the order of $2$ in $\mod 2^{n} -1 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the order of $2$ in  $\mod 2^n-1$

---

I know that the order of $2$ in $\mod  2^n-1$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that
$$2^k  \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n-1}$$

How to proceed from here ? Any help/hints ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you we use $\mod 2^n-1$ it is clear that $k$ must be greater than $n-1$ because $2^{n-1}\leq 2^n-1$ If you try $k=n$ you see that $2^k = 2^n \equiv 1 (\mod 2^n-1)$

Comment: Is that because for the numbers less than $2^n-1$, the remainder would be the number itself and can never be $1$ ?

Comment: Exactly. For $0<k<n$ you have $2\leq 2^k\leq2^n-1$

Comment: Very nice :) thanks !!

Comment: nico! nico! hehe